# method will recurse infinitly

Tags: java, methods

a super silly question but why does the method prime recurse infinitely ?
this is a simple java code where i'm trying to make a method i can call to get the prime of parameter x , but it tells me that the method will recurse infinitely , i tried copy pasting the code of the prime method to the main method and it worked well , so can someone help please?

`

```
import java.util.*;

public class Mavenproject2 {

    static int prime(int x) {
        boolean f = true;
        if (x == 1 || x == 0) {
            f = false;
        } else {

            for (int i = 2; i < x; i++) {
                if (x % i == 0) {
                    f = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (f) {
            System.out.println("prime");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not prime");
        }

        return prime(x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter number");
        int x = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(prime(x));

    }
}
```

`

Comment: "why does the method prime recurse infinitely" what do you think `return prime(x);` does?

Comment: i thought it calls the prime method but i'm obviously wrong so what does it do? am i phrasing it wrongly?  really asking bec i  just learnt methods today

Comment: yes, it call prime method from prime method - it is definition of recursion

Comment: i still don't get it sorry , so how should i write it? do i just say return prime?

Comment: so no , i tried it and it gave me an error obviously, so really how can i solve this?

Comment: You need a "base case" or terminating condition, as well as a step condition which reduces toward the base case - your `x` never changes so that fails the second condition.

Comment: What is the value of `x` every time you call `prime(x)`? Does the value of `x` ever change?

Comment: i see thank you a lot guys, i will try to study about methods again and give it another go bec i clearly don't understand it quite well yet, though truly thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know if the number passed in is prime. You need to change your return type to a bool and return f.

You're returning prime(x) which will keep calling into itself.

I would actually do something like this

```
import java.util.*;

public class Mavenproject2 {

    static string prime(int x) {
        boolean f = true;
        if (x == 1 || x == 0) {
            f = false;
        } else {

            for (int i = 2; i < x; i++) {
                if (x % i == 0) {
                    f = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (f) {
            return "prime";
        } 

        return "not prime";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter number");
        int x = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(prime(x));

    }
}
```

Comment: oh it worked! thank you so much, i'll study again about methods and give it another try but truly thank you a lot.